# Post Input OnChange with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Just some AJAX troubleshooting.

**Context:** Building a large table with input that should post as soon as their filled out. Thought the onchange trigger would work best.

**Issue:** I can't seem to get the javascript to pass the value of the input over to the .php sheet.

---

**header.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".matchedit").onchange(function postinput(){ // Problem 1: change(
    var matchvalue = $(this).value; // Problem 2: $(this).val();
    $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: 'matchedit-data.php',
            data: {matchvalue: matchvalue},
            type: 'post'
        });
  });
});
```

**page.php**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="grp1" type="text" class="matchedit" onchange="postinput()">
  </td>
</tr>
```

**matchedit-data.php**

```
$entry = $_POST['matchvalue'];
$conn->query("UPDATE matches SET grp = '$entry' WHERE mid = 'm1'");
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Beware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: thanks - but this will only be available for my use, and won't be a public page.

Comment: That makes sense. Please note that for reading the value of a jQuery wrapped input `.val()` method should be used instead. Also you should either use `.on('change')` or `change()` method, jQuery object doesn't have `onchange` method.

Comment: @undefined - I used change() and now its posting, but the value isn't being posted.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: The errors are pretty obvious if you use a decent browser script debugger.  I'm still using Firebug.  Which one do you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For reading the value of a jQuery wrapped input `.val()` method should be used, `value` here returns an `undefined` value. Also you should either use `.on('change')` or `change()` method, jQuery object doesn't have `onchange` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".matchedit").on('change', function postinput(){
        var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'matchedit-data.php',
            data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function(responseData) {
            console.log('Done: ', responseData);
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('Failed');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's now posting, however its literally shooting blanks. The value isn't being picked up. When I assign var matchvalue a value manually, it passes through. Something isn't working with my execution of  $(this).val()

Comment: @JamesPatrick You can check the length of the value, `$.trim(matchvalue).length`, if it's more than 0 send the request otherwise `return`.

Comment: @undefined this is perfect code, after two hours I got the working code. Thanks buddy.