# Using an onclick event to run a query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using php to echo rows out of a database into a dropdown submenu.

Should the user want to edit any specific record displayed in the submenu, I would like to be able to do it without requiring the user to click additional submit buttons.

I know the best way would be to use javascript.  I have a function called when the user clicks on the record, passing the record ID as a parameter to the function.

I however do not know how to proceed. Ideally I would like to POST it to the same page and then go on with the php.

How would the best way be to go about this

Comment: Do some research on AJAX, it looks like you are half way there anyway

Comment: Similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712799/post-input-onchange-with-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var id = elem.val();
$.ajax({
        url: "page.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: id }
      }).done(function(msg) {
        // Do something
        })
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus + " - Please try again.")
      })
```

You will need to add a link to jquery if you are not already using it.  I would suggest reading up on ajax as well so you understand what it is doing and how to use it correctly.